# Which value does atomic read operation with memory_order_seq_cst read in this situation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

I've read the chapters about memory ordering in the c++11 standard and confused by a rule. According to the C++11 standard (ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N3690), 29.3 3, it's said that:

> There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst operations, consistent with the “happens before” order and modification orders for all affected locations, such that each memory_order_seq_cst operation B that loads a value from an atomic object M observes one of the following values: 
> — the result of the last modification A of M that precedes B in S, if it exists, or
> — if A exists, the result of some modification of M in the visible sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not memory_order_seq_cst and that does not happen before A, or
> — if A does not exist, the result of some modification of M in the visible sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not memory_order_seq_cst.

So, consider the following situation:

There are 4 atomic operations **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**.  From the code:

- All of them are operations on the same atomic variable
- **A** and **B** are write operations with any order (may be relaxed)
- **C** is write operation with memory_order_seq_cst
- **D** is read operation with memory_order_seq_cst
- **A** is the last write operation that *happens-before* **D**
- **A**, **B**, **C** does not have happens-before relationship mutually.
- **D**, **B**, **C** does not have happens-before relationship mutually.

**Consider an execution where the following orderings happen to occur:**

- **C** appears before **D** in the single total order for memory_order_seq_cst operations
- The modification order on this variable appears like **A**->**B**->**C**

Here is the possible code

```
using namespace std;

atomic_bool go(false);
atomic_int var(0);

void thread1()
{
    while (!go) {}
    var.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);              // A
    this_thread::yield();
    cout << var.load(memory_order_seq_cst) << endl;  // D
}

void thread2()
{
    while (!go) {}
    var.store(2, memory_order_seq_cst);              // C
}

void thread3()
{
    while (!go) {}
    var.store(3, memory_order_relaxed);              // B
}

int main() {
    thread t1(thread1);
    thread t2(thread2);
    thread t3(thread3);
    go = true;
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Is it possible that read operation **D** will read the value written by operation **B**, given an A,B,C modification-order for `var`?

If not possible, what rules exclude this possibility?

If possible, this means that `memory_order_seq_cst` could read the value "written before" the last `memory_order_seq_cst` write. Is this a "bug" in C++ standard, or designed intentionally when not everything is seq_cst?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is possible that D reads either from A, B or C.

Consider a graph with four nodes: A, B, C and D.
And edges (sc: sequential consistent (total) ordering (C --sc--> D), sb: sequenced before / happens before (A --sb--> D), mo: modification order (A --mo--> B --mo--> C), and rf: Read From (? --rf--> D)).

There are two reasons why an rf edge in the graph would be inconsistent with the C++ memory model: causality and because you can't read from hidden visual side effects.

If you ignore sc edges for a moment, then -- having just a single atomic variable, the only causal restriction on the graph is to not have loops involving rf edges and (directed) sb edges (this is a result from [my research](https://github.com/CarloWood/memorymodel)). In this case no such loop can even exist since you only have a single rf edge-- so, there is no reason whatsoever that you can't read from any of the three writes.

However, you specify both, the exact modification order (not that this matters IMHO, you should only be interested in the possible outcomes of the program), as well as one sc edge. And we still have to investigate if those are compatible with each of the three possible rf edges with regard to reading from a hidden visual side effect.

Note that a given rf edge introduces a synchronization if its write node is release and the read node is acquire; sc is release/acquire, so the latter is true and the former only when reading from node C. However that synchronization means never more than (in modification order) everything before the write must happen before everything after the read; and there is nothing after the read, so the whole synchronization doesn't matter.

Moreover, the dictated modification order (A --mo--> B --mo--> C) is not causally inconsistent with the dictated total sc ordering (C --sc--> D) because D is a read and not part of the modification order subgraph. The only thing that is not allowed (because of causality) are directed loops involving sc and mo edges.

Now, as an experiment, assume we make node A also sc. Then we need to put A in the total ordering, thus either A --sc--> C --sc--> D, C --sc--> A --sc--> D or C --sc--> D --sc--> A, but we have A --mo--> C, so the latter two are disallowed (would cause a (causal) loop) and the only possible ordering is: A --sc--> C --sc--> D. Now it no longer is possible to read from A because that would cause the following subgraph:

```
A --sc--> C
|        /
|       /
|      /
rf    sc
|    /
|   /
|  /
v v
D
```

and the write in C will always overwrite the value that was written by A before it is being read by D (aka, A is a hidden visual side effect for D).

If A is not sc (as is the case in the original problem), then this rf is only disallowed (because of hidden vse) when

```
A --hb--> C
|        /
|       /
|      /
rf    sc
|    /
|   /
|  /
v v
D
```

where 'hb' stands for Happens-Before (for the same reason; then A is a hidden visual side effect for D, as C will always overwrite the value written by A before D reads it).

In the original problem there is no happens-before between thread 1 and 2 however, because such synchronization would require another rf edge between the two threads (or a fence or anything that would cause the extra synchronization).

Finally, yes this is intended behavior and not a bug in the standard.

**Edit**

To quote the standard that you quoted:

> — the result of the last modification A of M that precedes B in S, if
>   it exists, or

The A here is your C, and the B here is your D. The A mentioned here DOES exist, namely node C (C --sc--> D). So this line says that it is possible to read the value written by node C.

> — if A exists, the result of some modification of M in the visible
>   sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not
>   `memory_order_seq_cst` and that does not happen before A, or

Again, the A here is your C and it exists. Then the "result of some modification of M (var) in the visible sequence of side effects with respect to B (your D) that is *not* `memory_order_seq_cst`" is your A. And as we have established, your A does not happen before your C (their A). So, this says that it is possible to read the value written from your A.

> — if A does not exist, the result of some modification of M in the
>   visible sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not
>   `memory_order_seq_cst`.

This is not relevant here and would only apply when there wasn't a write in the total ordering S of M (var) that came before B (your D).

Answer (score 1):

Even with **A**->**B**->**C** as the *"modification order"*, **B** is a possibility because it *"is not memory_order_seq_cst and that does not happen before [**C**]"*.

The standard definition for *visible sequence of side effects* ([1.10.14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro#multithread-14)) supports this (emphasis mine):

> The *visible sequence of side effects* on an atomic object *M*, with respect to a value computation *B* of *M*, is a maximal contiguous sub-sequence of side effects in the modification order of *M*, where the first side effect is visible with respect to *B*, and for every side effect, it is not the case that *B* happens before it. The value of an atomic object *M*, as determined by evaluation *B*, shall be the value stored by **some** operation in the visible sequence of *M* with respect to *B*.

So even with an explicit *modification order*, your load can yield **A**, **B**, or **C**.